# Combining "access-violation" and "segmentation-fault" tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

By my (potentially incorrect!) understanding, the terms "segmentation fault" and "access violation" mean the same thing, except that one is a Linux term and one is a Microsoft term.  However, they have separate tags, one with 800 questions and one with 200.  Can these be combined together into one tag?  If you're searching for information on how to resolve a segfault/access violation, then knowledge about the other is likely to be helpful to you.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say no to this as well. An access violation doesn't always imply a segmentation fault - and access violations occur in POSIX environments too (e.g. as detected by tools such as Valgrind, which can be the precursor to accessing another block that results in a segfault).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it would work really. I mean, if you use a tag synonym then one of them has to be the parent and it's going to be confusing from the "other camp" as to why theirs is being replaced.

The Tags are fairly important when it comes to searching so if someone types in "Access Violation" and all the questions now have the Tag "Segmentation-Fault", then likely those items will be less discoverable.